# Removing XFCE on fedora20

Tags: fedora, yum, xfce

I'm trying to remove XFCE from my fedora installation in favor of kde.  I tried `#yum remove @xfce` but I got this...

```
Running transaction check
ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:
desktop-backgrounds-compat is needed by (installed) lightdm-gtk-1.6.1-3.fc20.x86_64
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Might work: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/56445/how-i-remove-xfce-and-install-kde-desktop/

Comment: No I'm afraid that is what gives the error @slm

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the system was still using lightdm (xfce's display manager) instead of kde's display manager which is kdm.  To force the system to use kdm first I did `systemctl enable --force kdm.service` then restarted.  Followed by `yum remove lightdm-gtk-1.6.1-3.fc20.x86_64`.  Finally finished with `yum remove @xfce`

Should be useful to anyone who might have started with an xfce spin and decided to move to a different desktop.